Is it possible to install Self-hosted integration runtime on a FTP server?
I'm trying to create ADF pipelines for data linkage from a FTP server(Internal) to ADF.
And I want to build a Self-hosted integration runtime on a FTP server.(If it is possible.)
How should I do?
Thank you.

To install self-hosted integration runtime you need a windows machine (windows 8/1-11 or server 2022-2022).
See the full list of requirements here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites
You don't have to install the self-hosted integration runtime on the FTP server, you can install it on another server in the same network and make sure it has access to the FTP server.
For installation instructions of self-hosted integration runtime see here: self-hosted integration runtime
